# ASP.NET MVC Area not displaying my Custom Helpers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-areas

I created Area called Admin. I have Custom Helper in the root folder called Helpers which are working fine when I use @Html.MyHelper(); but I do the samething in my Area View folder Razor page I don't see MyHelper. I tried to add Namespaces in Area View config file but no success. Anyone tell me what I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by "Area View config file" (do you mean the web.config in your area?).

Try explicitly including the namespace in the CSHTML:

```
@using MvcWebApplication1.Helpers.MyCustomHelpers
```

Alternatively, you could register the namespace in **web.config:**

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="MvcWebApplication1.Helpers.MyCustomHelpers" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```

NOTE: There was an issue with namespace registration with Razor in MVC3 Preview, but has been fixed in beta / RC1. See [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2010/10/21/bug-fixes-and-changes-in-asp-net-mvc-3-beta.aspx) for more info.

Comment: Yes Web.config in Area. I don't want to do Using. Can there be a Global place to put namespaces. I try that using also.

Comment: @pirzada - you can use `@using`, OR register in web.config. see my edit

Comment: Strange if I am using Namespace like 

@using myproject.Web.Helpers

which is working fine but if I am putting that in Area web.config file like

<system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
      
          <add namespace="myproject.Web.Helpers"/>
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
  
  is not working. Meaning my Custom helper not showing in intelli.

Comment: Is there a link to documentation regarding this?